# where to find opencv-contrib-python-nonfree now?

Tags: python

I tried to install opencv-contrib-python-nonfree using pip install opencv-contrib-python-nonfree. and it says the below error. I googled it and i found the below website says it is gone. so is there an alternative?  I can install opencv-contrib-python no problem. The reason I need nonfree version is because of the error when calling SURF algorithm like this: surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(8000). So how to solve it? I need to use SURF algorithem. Thanks

https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/348

```
the error when install opencv-contrib-python-nonfree:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python-nonfree (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python-nonfree

The error when using SURF

import cv2

img = cv2.imread('../images/varese.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(8000)
keypoints, descriptors = surf.detectAndCompute(gray, None)

error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-i1s8y2i1\opencv_contrib\modules\xfeatures2d\src\surf.cpp:1029: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) This algorithm is patented and is excluded in this configuration; Set OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE CMake option and rebuild the library in function 'cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::create'
```

Answer (score 3):

There is the issue: https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/126

You can install with pip build the package with the NONFREE flag set.

```
CMAKE_ARGS="-DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON" pip install -v --no-binary=opencv-contrib-python opencv-contrib-python==4.5.3.56
```

Because of the latest version isn't correctly installed, try to install the previous version.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, do I need to remove CMAKE_ARGS="-DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON"?  it says: 'CMAKE_ARGS' is not recognized as an internal or external command, Thanks

Comment: No, you need it. This is an environment variable which `cmake` will takes that you could use SURF algorithms.